# Ambassador load-balancer is empty

Tags: load-balancing

I am new to Ambassador and trying to debug some installation issues.
I am following these instructions https://www.getambassador.io/docs/edge-stack/latest/tutorials/getting-started/ and getting stuck at step 3

My load balancer does not seem to connect properly $LB_ENDPOINT is empty

```
"status": {
        "loadBalancer": {}
    }
```

One big problem is that I do not know how to access the logs. All of my pods seem to be operating as expected(?)

Configuration:

I am using a bare metal installation of Kubernetes with 4 nodes.

Kubernetes v1.23.1

Cilium v1.11.0

Comment: you might want to show your config together with the question so people can more easily help you without blindly guessing.

Comment: @vautee I have added details. Is this what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I am using a bare metal installation, these instructions fixed it for me

https://www.getambassador.io/docs/edge-stack/latest/topics/install/bare-metal/